# Webservice throws "empty" exception

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I've a webservice which seems to works fine, but sometimes the webservice stop working for no apparent reason. When I check the response in Firebug I see an "empty" exception:
"There was an error processing the request"

When the error occurs none of the methods on the webservice is working - even the simplest methods which does nothing else but return some data from the database. What could cause a webservice to completly stop working?

Best regards,
Steffen

Answer (score 0):

I'd same problems a few years ago. By using PerfMon I saw that I've to increase the usable memory for the hosting AppPool..

When you're logic is fine, it has to be a configuration problem on your webserver (IIS)

Comment: I'm not an IIS expert at all, so I'm clueless about what to do. I checked the event log on the server, but there's no entries there. In the text log that IIS makes we can see some server errors (500), but no info about what went wrong. The first error comes from different webservice methods, so it's not in a specific method that the error occurs first. I would really appreciate your help if you could elaborate a bit more on what you did, when you had the problem.